# Who put the snake on the tap of the entrance to the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter, chamber-of-secrets

Hogwarts was supposed to have been built around a thousand years ago, but indoor plumbing dates back to only the mid 1800's.

In this case, who put the snake on the tap in Myrtle's bathroom in *The Chamber of Secrets*?

Comment: When I hear the phrase "snake on the tap", I can't help but think of it in the "beer" sense, as in, you turn on the tap and snake pours out.  "Pour me a nice long and scaly one, bartender!"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had forgotten that the snake on the tap is not only in the film, but in the book as well!

> They examined every inch of it,
> inside and out, including the pipes below. And then Harry saw it: scratched on the side of one of the copper taps was a tiny snake.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* - Chapter 16, The Chamber of Secrets</sub>

While we can't say for sure who added the snake to the taps, we can find from an article on Pottermore that a member of the Gaunt family added the sink when plumbing was introduced to Hogwarts:

> When first created, the Chamber was accessed through a concealed trapdoor and a series of magical tunnels. However, when Hogwarts’ plumbing became more elaborate in the eighteenth century (this was a rare instance of wizards copying Muggles, because hitherto they simply relieved themselves wherever they stood, and vanished the evidence), the entrance to the Chamber was threatened, being located on the site of a proposed bathroom. The presence in school at the time of a student called Corvinus Gaunt – direct descendant of Slytherin, and antecedent of Tom Riddle – explains how the simple trapdoor was secretly protected, so that those who knew how could still access the entrance to the Chamber even after newfangled plumbing had been placed on top of it.
> <sub>*Chamber of Secrets* by J.K. Rowling, accessed on [Pottermore](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/chamber-of-secrets)</sub>

This article explains (although it doesn't explain *how* he did it) that a Slytherin descendant ensured the concealment of the Chamber when Hogwarts introduced plumbing. I would presume that it is them who added the snake motif, although I can't find anything that says Corvinus Gaunt was definitely the one who added it, or who might have done it in the years after him. Perhaps the line "those who knew how could still access the entrance to the Chamber even after newfangled plumbing had been placed on top of it" alludes to the notion Corvinus marked the entrance in this way.

Comment: J.K. Rowling seems to be bad at maths again.  The 18th century would be from 1701-1800, while the 19th century, the era when indoor plumbing came into widespred use in the UK, was from 1801-1900.

Comment: Could be old Voldy too. The lazy dude.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Good spot! I'm not sure what's worse, such a bungling of the numbers (albeit in character), or that *someone* simply didn't look up the dates. What's far worse though is the article's disclosure that wizards *"relieved themselves wherever they stood"* prior to the introduction of Muggle plumbing :/

Comment: @M.A.Golding Scotland had modern flush toilets in the 18th century (1775 S-bend water seal patented), Something doesn't need to be commonplace to be copied, or the rest of the UK would never have had them.

Comment: What's unclear is why did wizards decide to adopt bathrooms, when relieving yourself wherever you stand (or sit, I guess) and vanishing the evidence seems A LOT easier. Also, wasn't there a scene in one of the books where Dumbledore entered the Room of Requirements and it was a bathroom, because he was in a hurry to use the toilet? Why wouldn't the (probably) most powerful and skilled wizard in the world just do it the old way?

Comment: @Blueriver I think the whole wizards vanishing their own body waste notion is entirely J.K. over egging the pudding.